# After doing ', g g' (spacemacs/jump-to-definition) how do I get back?

Tags: spacemacs

I did

```
, g g
```

to jump to the definition of same symbol under the point. Now I want
to return to my previous file/position.

Is there a binding for that?

What is the binding in a default spacemacs installation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use either `''` (Two single quotes) in normal mode or using `ctrl + o`.

In the first case `'` means 'go to mark' and the second `'` is the temporary mark register that automatically sets after any jump.

In the second case you can use to jump back step-by-step (So you can jump into previous buffer and all of the motions there)